# What is the version of Xpath expression supported by Wso2 ESB?

Tags: wso2-esb

Wso2 esb is not support for some xpath functions like name() which required to use in default name spaces. Which version of Xpath expressions supported by the wso2 esb.

Answer (score 2):

I found this [Blog Entry:[WSO2 ESB] Enable XPath 2.0](http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/01/wso2-esb-enable-xpath-20-in-wso2-esb.html), Think this will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

ESB supports XPath 1.0 out-of-the-box. In order to enable XPath 2.0 support you have to modify the ${ESB_HOME}/repository/conf/synapse.properties file as described in the following link:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Configuring+synapse.properties

You´ll create/edit the "synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled" and set its value to "true".